# Type requirements for std::list

Tags: c++

I've got a type that can't be moved or copied (by making the necessary constructors and operators private). But when I tried to compile a std::list of them, the operation failed with a very strange error (class name snipped for brevity).

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xmemory(202)
: error C2248: 'T::T' : cannot access private member declared in class 'T'
```

Surely it's not incumbent of a type in a linked list to be movable or copyable.

When these members are made public, the code compiles fine- even though, if the std::list had tried to access them, it would be an unresolved external, since they're only declared private. Makes no sense :(

Comment: "Surely it's not incumbent of a type in a linked list to be movable or copyable." Then how shall it get the value from outside the list to the inside of the list? :)

Comment: By using resize and default-constructing them. Why there's no explicit function to add a default-constructed one, I don't know.

Comment: Because, given that the container requirements explicitly states objects have to be copy-constructible, there isn't much reason to bother with one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of C++03, elements must be copy constructible and copy assignable. §23.1/3:

> The type of objects stored in these components must meet the requirements of CopyConstructible types (20.1.3), and the additional requirements of Assignable types.

In C++0x, requirements are put on a per-operation basis, but in general it's safe to say elements must be move constructible and move assignable. (Though some operations require copy constructibility and assign-ability, etc.)

A typical solution to your problem is to store pointers to objects, via `shared_ptr` or some other smart pointer.

Comment: But the code doesn't generate an error if they're public. Which it should, if they're required to be copyable, since they're only declared.

Comment: @DeadMG, that's because the compiler is eliding the copy and therefore not requiring the function to be defined. It still has to be accessible though.

Comment: That explains it. A pity that I can't mark a comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

standard containers need their element type to be copyable, if you have noncopyable types, use (smart) pointers as the element type instead (like: `std::list<boost::shared_ptr<YourType> >`.

template class/functions often generate errors unless you use them explicitly, so it could be that you havent got an error.