# std::list of pointers and remove_if

Tags: c++, stl

I'm doing some tests with a std::list of pointers. I'm using remove_if algorithm to eliminate some elements of the list. But I encountered some problems, remove_if is creating memory leaks because it doesn't destroy the pointers (I think).

I found a solution, but I don't know if it is well made, correct or at least acceptable...

Here is the code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

class Object
{
 private:
         int intData;   
 public:
        Object(int n) : intData(n) { };
        int getIntData(void) { return intData; };
        void setIntData(int n) { intData = n; };
};

/** Functor */
struct listFunctor
{ 
 bool operator()(Object* obj1, Object* obj2) const
 {
  return (obj1->getIntData() < obj2->getIntData());
 }
};

class removeFunctor
{
 private:
         int remover;
 public:
        removeFunctor(int n) : remover(n) { };
        bool operator()(Object* obj)
        {
         bool res = (obj->getIntData() != remover);

         if(res)
          delete obj;

         return res; 
        }
};

typedef list<Object*> objList;
typedef list<Object*>::iterator objectListIter;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
 objList objectList;

 objectList.push_back(new Object(8));
 objectList.push_back(new Object(0));
 objectList.push_back(new Object(2));

 /** sort elements. */
 objectList.sort(listFunctor());

 /** print. */
 for(objectListIter it = objectList.begin(); it != objectList.end(); ++it)
  cout<<*it<<"  "<<(*it)->getIntData()<<'\n';   

 /** remove. */
 objectListIter iter = remove_if(objectList.begin(), objectList.end(), removeFunctor(8));

 /** print. */
 for(objectListIter it = objectList.begin(); it != iter; ++it)
  cout<<*it<<"  "<<(*it)->getIntData()<<'\n';   

 /** delete list. */
 for(objectListIter it = objectList.begin(); it != iter; ++it)
  delete *it;   

 objectList.clear(); //IS THIS NECESSARY?

 return 0;
}
```

The program first creates the list, sort it an then removes some elements.

Is this code a good and viable solution to this problem? Valgrind's default scan doesn't report any problems but I'm doing more tests.

Thanks.

Comment: `typedef std::list<std::unique_ptr<Object*>> objList;`:  no `delete` required.  And, unless you really need pointers, don't use them at all and instead use `std::list<Object>`.  `delete` leads to pain and suffering.  Finally and unless you really, really need a linked list, `std::vector<Object>`.

Comment: This seems like a better fit for [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: unique_ptr is not copyable, so if you need to store a pointer from the first place you better go with std::shared_ptr, it should works fine.

Comment: @Fredrik **Why**, exactly, would you need to copy the unique_ptrs out of the container?

Comment: It is as I know type requirements of all objects stored in std::list, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077135/type-requirements-for-stdlist

Comment: @Fredrik : That's true of C++03, but `std::unique_ptr<>` is not in C++03 so obviously C++11 rules apply here.

Comment: @Fredrik: `unique_ptr` is movable, so it works fine in lists.  Don't tell people to use `shared_ptr` unless it's absolutely needed.

Comment: I don´t tell people to use shared_ptr, it was only a simple comment to James, and I simply forgot this is not correct if the compiler supports move semantics (C++11).

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: That should be `std::unique_ptr<Object>`, no? (Obviously too late to edit now.)

Comment: @GManNickG:  Yes, it should be that.  Oops.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Removing from a `list<Object*>` will only remove the pointers from the list.  You should prefer a `list<unique_ptr<Object>>` or a `list<shared_ptr<Object>>` which will automatically delete the objects pointed to when the smart pointers are removed from the list.

Comment: And as James said, because those prefer `std::list<Object>`, and before that prefer `std::vector<Object>`. The fewer pointers the better.